# Why does a NodeJS ssl server respond to cURL with (52) Empty reply from server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, https

I am able to successfully reach a NodeJS server with ssl using the following command:

```
curl --insecure https://ipaddress
```

But I am getting (52) Empty reply from server when using the following command:

```
curl --insecure ipaddress:443
```

How can I make the latter work?
I need to specify the address in a DNS that does not appear to accept the former.

My curl version is `7.68.0` and appears to be up to date.

Comment: https protocol != 443 protocol

Comment: @Saddy I am not certain how to answer your statement. The server monitors 443 and has ssl certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> curl --insecure ipaddress:443

Given that no explicit `https://` is given, curl will the default protocol HTTP. Only, the server expects HTTPS on port 443 and thus the request will fail. There is no way to make this plain HTTP working, since the server does not expect plain HTTP on this port.

> curl --insecure https://ipaddress

In this case it was explicitly `https://` given. Thus it will use HTTPS on port 443 (default for HTTPS) and succeed.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any way to tell cURL to use https protocol without the https prefix?

Comment: @user3877654: No. That's exactly what the URL prefix is for.